# Extract the weights from a TensorFlow graph to use them in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

i have a Tensorflow graph (output_graph.pb) that I obtained by doing transfer learning on Inception V3 following [this tutorial](https://www.tensorflow.org/hub/tutorials/image_retraining). Now I need to extract the weights of the individual layers to import them onto the model created with Keras. I know that it is not possible to directly convert the graph from tensorflow into a keras model ([see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44896719/using-a-tensorflow-pb-graph-as-a-keras-model)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can retrieve individual layer weights as a NumPy array within the context of a TensorFlow session by invoking `sess.run(var)` on a trainable weight tensor `var`. In a Keras model, a specified layer's weights can be set manually using `model.layers[index].set_weights([weight_matrix, bias_vector])`, where `model` is an instance of a Sequential or Functional model.

Note that you'll also need to obtain a trainable bias vector in your TensorFlow script in a similar manner to retrieving the weight matrix, as a `Dense` layer in a Keras model expects both a weight tensor and a bias vector fed as a list of NumPy arrays.